# Strings that are initialized in a different place than they are declared

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to read the title from a webpage and save it as a String. However, since Strings are immutable in java, I can't just set it to null and change it when I need to. Therefore, I'm getting an error on the next to last line that `strTitle` may not have been initialized. This seems like it should be easy to deal with, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

```
  URL allRecipe = new URL(inputLine); //user defined url
    BufferedReader urlIn = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(allRecipe.openStream()));

  String inputFromWeb;

  //loops through webpage and finds title 
  while((inputFromWeb = urlIn.readLine()) != null){
    //getting title
    if(inputFromWeb.contains("<title>")){
        strTitle = urlIn.readLine();
    }

  }//end while
  urlIn.close();

  //print out title
  System.out.println("Title:");
  System.out.println(strTitle); //this line returns the error
  System.out.println("\n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since strings are immutable in java and I can't just set it to null
>   and change it when I need to.

Sure you can. If you are initializing a String reference to null and then assigning to it a different String, you are not changing any String, you are just changing the String reference.

> However, as is I'm getting an error on the next to last line that
>   strTitle may not have been initialized.

`String strTitle = null;`

will solve your problem.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know that. I thought strings couldn't be changed in any way once they are declared. I suppose I should have just tried it. 

Is this the case because setting the string's value to null doesn't count as initializing it, since null isn't really a value?

Comment: @PsylentKnight It has nothing to do with setting it to null. You can also write `String s = "x";s="y";` In this case you are not changing the value of the String from "x" from "y", you are assigning a new String to the s variable.

Comment: Apparently I didn't fully understand the whole concept of the immutability of strings. I've read a little more and I think I get it now. As I understand it, the code in your last comment makes s reference a different memory location, leaving the old memory location behind as garbage, which java then disposes of.